# How to make folder and use to upload file into it in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxuploader

I have developed web management document using ASP.NET.
I confused about how to make specific folder according "User Profile". So the schema likes when user upload their document, it is automatically create a folder according their Profile (ex: if Admin Finance upload their document, it's automatically create a folder name 'Finance' and the file uploaded to it but it only done for the first time).
For upload file I use AjaxUploader.

Below my upload code using Ajax Uploader:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="FileUpload_Preview.aspx.vb" Inherits="MRISO_FileUpload.FileUpload_Preview" %>

<%@ Register Namespace="CuteWebUI" Assembly="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader" TagPrefix="CuteWebUI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style/demo.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
            }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
            });
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dataTable').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "Todo"]]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#gvFileDetails").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
            $('#gvFileDetails').DataTable();
            $('input[type=search]').on("keyup", function () {
                var searchTerm = $(this).val();
                $(".forHighlight").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + searchTerm + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>

    <script runat="server">
        Private Sub InsertMsg(ByVal msg As String)
            ListBoxEvents.Items.Insert(0, msg)
            ListBoxEvents.SelectedIndex = 0
        End Sub

        Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnInit(e)
            SubmitButton.Attributes("onclick") = "return submitbutton_click()"
        End Sub

        Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            InsertMsg("You have uploaded " & uploadcount & "/" & Uploader1.Items.Count & " files.")
        End Sub

        Private uploadcount As Integer = 0

        Private Sub Uploader_FileUploaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UploaderEventArgs)
            uploadcount += 1

            Dim uploader As Uploader = DirectCast(sender, Uploader)
            InsertMsg("File uploaded! " & args.FileName & ", " & args.FileSize & " bytes.")

            'Copys the uploaded file to a new location. 
            args.CopyTo("../Forms/UploadFile/" & args.FileName)
            'You can also open the uploaded file's data stream. 
            'System.IO.Stream data = args.OpenStream()
            Dim data As System.IO.Stream = args.OpenStream
        End Sub

        Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
            SubmitButton.Attributes("itemcount") = Uploader1.Items.Count.ToString()

            MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
        End Sub
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Upload Your File
            </h2>
            <p>
                This web is using for all Admin department to upload their document.<br /><br />

                Regards,<br />
                <u><b>JSS</b></u>
            </p>
            <CuteWebUI:UploadAttachments runat="server" ManualStartUpload="true" ID="Uploader1"
                InsertText="Browse Files (Max 20M)" OnFileUploaded="Uploader_FileUploaded">
                <ValidateOption AllowedFileExtensions="*.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.pdf" MaxSizeKB="20480" />
            </CuteWebUI:UploadAttachments>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" runat="server" />&nbsp&nbsp
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Back to Home" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxEvents" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function submitbutton_click() {
                    var submitbutton = document.getElementById('<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>');
                    var uploadobj = document.getElementById('<%=Uploader1.ClientID %>');
                    if (!window.filesuploaded) {
                        if (uploadobj.getqueuecount() > 0) {
                            uploadobj.startupload();
                        }
                        else {
                            var uploadedcount = parseInt(submitbutton.getAttribute("itemcount")) || 0;
                            if (uploadedcount > 0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            alert("Please browse files for uploading");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    window.filesuploaded = false;
                    return true;
                }
                function CuteWebUI_AjaxUploader_OnPostback() {
                    window.filesuploaded = true;
                    var submitbutton = document.getElementById('<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>');
                    submitbutton.click();
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <%-- This tab is displayed the uploaded data and categories by Department --%>
        <div id="gridview" class="content">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menuOne">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                General Department
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menuOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="Script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvFileDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" EmptyDataText="No File Uploaded" runat="server">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#(gvFileDetails.PageSize * gvFileDetails.PageIndex) + gvFileDetails.Rows.Count + 1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="forHighlight" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="50%" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' OnClick="DeleteFile" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this file?')" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlOpen" Text="View" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Value", "~/ViewPage.aspx?fileName={0}") %>' Target="_blank" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menuTwo">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                Tab Kedua
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menuTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            This tab is empty. Waiting for the data...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menuThree">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                Tab Ketiga
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menuThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            This tab is empty. Watingn for the data...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the create folder code :

```
Dim path As String = "F:\Upload Document Dept\ " & Session("profile")

If Not (Directory.Exists(path)) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    lblMsg.Text = "Folder Succesfully create."
Else
    lblMsg.Text = "Directory already exists."
End If
```

I don't know how to make it working together, like I say above. Please help me guys. Thank :)

Comment: Presumably that code, or something similar, would go into the `Uploader_FileUploaded` handler, since that's the code which runs when a file is uploaded. Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes you're right man. The document inserted into specific folder that i have declare in above code (in this line "args.CopyTo("../Forms/UploadFile/" & args.FileName)"). I want that document insert into folder that generate when i click button based on admin profile simultaneously.

Comment: Ok. So have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Can you edit the code above with your suggest?

Comment: Well firstly, where do you actually want to save your files to? In the FileUploaded method you save them to `../Forms/UploadFile/` but in your little "create directory" sample, your path is `F:\Upload Document Dept\ ` ...so which is correct?

Comment: I want to save them in F:\Upload Document Dept\'Profile Name'\. So when Admin upload their documents, it's automatically create a folder inside folder 'Upload Document Dept' according Admin Profile. So, every Admin have their own folder that different with others. Above i have successfully make upload function and create folder. But i don't know how to make them work together with the scenario.

Comment: Ok...so...if you place your "create folder" code snippet at the start of your Uploader_FileUpload method, and then change the string inside the "copyTo" command to point to the right folder, what's the result? That's all I was suggesting, nothing too complicated. Like I said, give it a try. If you still get stuck, update the question to show what exactly you did, and what error or problem is occurring.